# Удаление части текста в предложении между двумя словами

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

У меня есть текст и каждый раз он разный. В него попадает часто такое предложение несколько раз:

> Расстояние до филармонии 5 км.

Мне нужно удалять часть текста на питоне от слова Расстояние до символа точка. Точно не могу знать какие слова будут после слова Расстояние до символа точка. На Питоне есть функция re.findall и я не могу разобраться как в ней сделать шаблон поиска для всех появляющихся таких предложений. Версия Питона 3.7.1.

```
import re
val = str(input("Введите текст: "))
result = re.search('(Расстояние) +(\.)', val)
if result:
   print (result.group(0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать шаблон `Расстояние.*?\.`
Найти и заменить вхождение можно с помощью функции `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

```
import re
val = str(input("Введите текст: "))
result = re.sub("Расстояние.*?\.", "", val)
print(result)
```